# How to calculate Weighted Average in Power BI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data table looks like this:

```
Country | Total | Days 
A | 56 | 3
B | 23  | 5
C | 22 | 2
D | 90 | BLANK
```

I want to find the weighted average which consists of 4 steps

```
Step 1 : Multiply Total into Days where Days is not blank (i.e to consider only non blank values). lets name the new column formed "Product:
Step 2 : Take the Subtotal sum of the PRODUCT
Step 3 : Take the Subtotal sum of TOTAL
Step 4 : Step 2 / Step 3
```

I am unable to do this in Power BI even though it is done on the EXCEL.
Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the below measure -

```
Measure 2 = DIVIDE(sumx('Table','Table'[Days]*'Table'[Total]), SUM('Table'[Total]))
```